non-quadratic function with gradients of the same order everywhere that has an equilibrium point?
I want to find an example of a pair of functions of (at least) two variables $X(x,y)$ and $Y(x,y)$ that have a known equilibrium point but the gradients with respect to the variable of the name of the function must be all of the same order everywhere, namely $\nabla_x X(x,y) = \Theta (\nabla_y Y(x,y))$ in Landau notation. (If there are more than two variables think of $x$ as some of them and $y$ as the rest)
I am aware this always holds if the gradients have the same formula of $x$ and $y$ but with a multiplicative constant of difference, say, we pick $\nabla_xX(x,y) = (x-1)(y-2)$ and $\nabla_yY(x,y) = 2(x-1)(y-2)$. Integrating this gives us the pair $X(x,y) = \frac{(x-1)^2}{2}(y-2)$ and $Y(x,y) = (x-1)(y-2)^2$.
The problem is that this example doesn't have an equilibrium point...
In fact I've been trying polynomials but they always seem to come with odd degree for one variable and even for the other, and then there is a inflection/minimum point instead. I figure this will always happen, since I'm picking the same gradients so integrating the degree of the polynomials is always going to yield 1 unit of difference.
I also tried picking something like sine and cosine, but I always end up finding functions that have inflection/minimum points and not equilibrium following this approach starting from the gradients and integrating...
So is there a pair of functions satisfying these properties?
